# Sending files from Windows 10 to instrument running Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-transfer

I have a recently installed Windows 10 machine, which interfaces with several instruments in my laboratory.

However, I have come across a problem when trying to use an instrument which runs an OEM version of Windows XP Pro SP3.
The issue is related to SMB1 not being active on Windows 10, and I do not have admin access to the Win10 computer to enable it (I do have admin access on the instrument, which is on a local network), nor would company policies allow it, probably.

I can communicate with the instrument using VISA, which is the main communication protocol I use for all instruments, but I need to load different text files into this one. Each file is generated by my Win10 machine and saved to a shared folder. This is not possible anymore.

My question is, is there a way to transfer a file to the WinXP instrument without enabling SMB1?

---

### EDIT

I think I need to provide some more details.

What I currently do is use LabVIEW to:

- Generate the file and save it to the shared folder
- Send a command to the instrument to retrieve the file and load it

This is done several times per minute, so using a USB key or email to transfer the file is not feasible. I need something that can be somehow automated.

Comment: The way I have done this on a VM (X)) without enabling SMBv1 on the Host Windows 10 machine is via a USB key.  If you can enable Email on the XP machine (even web mail), you can send the files by Email.

Comment: Unfortunately USB is not feasible, as I need to change the file contents several times in a few minutes, this would terribly increase the time of my experiment. Same goes for email, I need something that can be automated. I will edit the question with more details.

Comment: An automatic routine with two different and incompatible versions of SMB might be a bit of a stretch.  I will keep looking around.  I do have XP here to see if I can do something.

Comment: If you aren't worried about traffic inside of your network, use a simple minimal FTP or SFTP server.. like [this](https://www.xlightftpd.com/) one.  IIS is a bloat monster.. even in XP.. when all you want is file transfer.  If you don't like the FTP server I suggest, there are many more.. also for free.. also lightweight and easy to administer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable SMBv1 protocol on Windows 10 to do direct file sharing between windows 10 and XP. As you don't have administrative privileges then you can setup a private FTP server on XP.

Windows XP Professional comes with IIS 5 Xpress web server in installation CD-ROM. In XP machine, Insert the CD, and then run SETUP.exe (It should run automatically if Autoplay is enabled and AutoRun.inf should contain it), click Add or remove windows components and enable Internet Information Services (IIS) 5.
Restart if needed.

Now go to Start > Control Panel > Administrative tools > Internet Information Services (IIS) 5 manager. Then click + next to the computer name. Now expand FTP sites, and click Play button in Default FTP site. Now FTP server is running.

Now copy all files in C:\Intetpub\FTPROOT and now you can access it using the local IP address of XP machine and download them from any computer connected to network.

Comment: I don't think you can install IIS 5 Xpress without admin privs.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The user does not have administrative priviliges on only Windows 10.

Comment: The instrument runs an OEM version of XP Pro SP3, whose CD I have no idea where to find (it is an almost 20 year old instrument, after all). I might have a WinXP Pro SP1 CD, would that work as well?

Comment: Well I don't recommend using an SP1 CD, i recommend you to download a SP3 ISO and burn it into a CD then insert it.

Comment: DOUGH! .. I got that backwards :P

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run an HTTP server on the Windows 10 computer. There are a [lot](https://static-web-server.net/download-and-install/) [of](https://github.com/rif/spark) [options](http://fenixwebserver.com/) that don't require admin privileges. You can even use the HTTP server [built into LabView](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/tutorial-creating-and-publishing-a-labview-web-service-to-the-application-web-server-real-time-windows.html) (If you want to get really fancy, you could wait to generate the file until the HTTP request came in, then stream the data directly to the client).

You would need to modify your "Send a command to the instrument to retrieve the file and load it" logic to make the XP computer retrieve the file over HTTP.